# VHDL Problems when shifting BCD bits

Tags: components, vhdl, hardware

I have created a shift register that shifts 4 bits at once, because I give it as an input a BCD 3 digit number and each digit is represented by 4 bits, let's say 876 represented as 100001110110.

In the code I give it a temporary variable that holds all the bits and then gets reassigned the removed bits at the leftmost 4 bits after I have shifted all the bits 4 places to the right.

For example: 100001110110 -- before the shift
             011010000111 -- after the shift
I want my outputs to be the new 12 bit number after I shift (011010000111) and the 4 bits that got "shifted out" (0110).

**The following is the code:**

```
library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
          use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
          use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity SR4B is 
    port(CLK: IN STD_LOGIC;
         EN : IN STD_LOGIC;
         I_DATA: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
         O_DATA: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
         N_DATA: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0));
end SR4B;

architecture SR4BA of SR4B is

    begin

        process(CLK)
        variable tempv: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
        variable test_variable: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
        begin
            tempv := I_DATA;
            if (EN = '1') then
                if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
                    O_DATA <= tempv(3 DOWNTO 0);
                    for i in 0 to 3 loop
                        test_variable(i) := tempv(i+4);
                        test_variable(i+4) := tempv(i+8);
                    end loop;
                    test_variable(11 DOWNTO 8) := tempv(3 DOWNTO 0);
                    tempv := test_variable;
                end if;
            else
                N_DATA <= I_DATA;
            end if;
        end PROCESS;

end SR4BA;
```

I loop over the bits and then replace them by the bits that are 4 places to the left of them. I assign the new 11 bits to N_DATA (new data) and I assign before the loop the 4 bits that I am about to shift to O_DATA (output data). I don't understand why it gives me X's everywhere when I simulate, I think the logic of my work is fine.

I can't see the error in the code so I need help and advice.

**The following is the testbench:**

```
library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.std_logic_arith.all; 
          use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity SR4BT is
end SR4BT;

architecture SR4BTA of SR4BT is
    component SR4B 
        port(CLK: IN STD_LOGIC;
                 EN : IN STD_LOGIC;
                 I_DATA: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
                 O_DATA: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
             N_DATA: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0));
    end component;

    signal CLK : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    signal EN  : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    signal I_DATA: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := "100001110110";
    signal O_DATA1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal O_DATA2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal O_DATA3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal N1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
    signal N2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
    signal N3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);

    begin
        u1 : SR4B port map(CLK,EN,I_DATA,O_DATA1,N1);
        u2 : SR4B port map(CLK,EN,N1,O_DATA2,N2);
        u3 : SR4B port map(CLK,EN,N2,O_DATA3,N3);

        PROCESS(CLK)    
        BEGIN
        CLK <= not CLK after 5 ns;
        END PROCESS;
end SR4BTA;
```

**The following is the simulation error:**

[Click to check the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYyEV.png)

Comment: The real question I read is *" why it gives me X's everywhere when I simulate"* If you search for "X in simulation" in stackoverflow you will get ~3000 hits, 95% of which have all the same cause: no initialization or reset

Comment: I already did search everywhere that's why I'm posting it here

Comment: Well: your variables have no initialization or reset. In HDL it is simplest to always have a reset.

Comment: I understand now, thank you it has solved everything.